# Resize SVG to 100% width but keep circles radius, how to do that?

Tags: css, svg

We use SVG to draw line graphs:

[image]

By design, the width should be 100%, so its exact value is unknown when SVG is generated. **preserveAspectRatio="none"** makes SVG to fill the 100% width, but it distortes the circles.

We save lines from distortion using **vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"** option; is there some trick to keep circles radius the same when scaling SVG?

Comment: Can you give a coded example instead of just images?

Comment: The sample is here - https://codepen.io/jury-gerasimov/pen/XqXpBz

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to replace *circle* with *line* of zero length but round caps. So each "circle" will look like -

```
<line x1="x" y1="y" x2="x" y2="y" 
style="stroke:#00a7e1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:13px;vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke" />
```

Comment: Great solution without having to adjust the SVG too much.  Thanks for posting!